# spark sql execution of except() query takes lot time

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the below code in spark application

```
val log_file_df = loadInputFile() /*loads log file as Dataframe */
val split_df: DataFrame = splitLineByDelimiter(log_file_df) /* applies filter 
                                                    function to input file */
val bad_data_df: DataFrame = parseAndSaveBadData(split_df) /*filters split dataframe into bad data */

val good_data_df = split_df.except(bad_data_df) /* separates good data from bad data */
```

If i run any action such as show() on split_df,bad_data_df , its taking less time to execute (around 1.5 mins) and I checked physical plan input log file is read only once

but if i run any action on good data its taking more time comparatively.(4 mins)

```
val good_data_df = split_df.except(bad_data_df).show()
```

From physical plan input log file is read twice . I tried with below options

```
    split_df.cache() or split_df.createOrReplaceTempView("split_dfTable")
//   Init.getSparkSession.sqlContext.cacheTable("split_dfTable")
     val splitbc =  Init.getSparkSession.sparkContext.broadcast(split_df)
```

But there is no improvement in time of execution and physical plan is same.
Here is the physical plan for. How should i improve  my code? My good_data_df is further transformed and joined with some other data frame which is taking more time.

```
good_data_df.show(false)good_data_df.explain(true)

 +- Exchange hashpartitioning(hostname#16, date#17, path#18, status#19,
    content_size#20, 200)
 +- *HashAggregate(keys=[hostname#16, date#17, path#18, status#19, 
      content_size#20], functions=[], output=[hostname#16, date#17, path#18, 
       status#19, content_size#20])
   +- SortMergeJoin [coalesce(hostname#16, ), coalesce(date#17, ), 
                   coalesce(path#18, ), coalesce(status#19, ), 
    coalesce(content_size#20, )], 
[coalesce(hostname#49, ), coalesce(date#50, ), coalesce(path#51, ), 
coalesce(status#52, ), coalesce(content_size#53, )], LeftAnti, 
(((((hostname#16 <=> hostname#49) && (date#17 <=> date#50)) && (path#18 <=> 
path#51)) && (status#19 <=> status#52)) && (content_size#20 <=> 
content_size#53))
:- *Sort [coalesce(hostname#16, ) ASC NULLS FIRST, coalesce(date#17, ) ASC 
NULLS FIRST, coalesce(path#18, ) ASC NULLS FIRST, coalesce(status#19, ) ASC 
NULLS FIRST, coalesce(content_size#20, ) ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(coalesce(hostname#16, ), coalesce(date#17, ), 
coalesce(path#18, ), coalesce(status#19, ), coalesce(content_size#20, ), 200)
:     +- *Project [regexp_extract(val#13, ^([^\s]+\s), 1) AS hostname#16, 
regexp_extract(val#13, ^.*(\d\d/\w{3}/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} -\d{4}), 1) AS 
date#17, regexp_extract(val#13, ^.*"\w+\s+([^\s]+)\s*[(HTTP)]*.*", 1) AS 
path#18, regexp_extract(val#13, ^.*"\s+([^\s]+), 1) AS status#19, 
regexp_extract(val#13, ^.*\s+(\d+)$, 1) AS content_size#20]
:        +- *FileScan csv [val#13] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: 
InMemoryFileIndex[file:/C:/Users/M1047320/Desktop/access_log_Jul95], 
PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<val:string>
+- *Sort [coalesce(hostname#49, ) ASC NULLS FIRST, coalesce(date#50, ) ASC 
NULLS FIRST, coalesce(path#51, ) ASC NULLS FIRST, coalesce(status#52, ) ASC 

NULLS FIRST, coalesce(content_size#53, ) ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
        +- Exchange hashpartitioning(coalesce(hostname#49, ), 
coalesce(date#50, ), coalesce(path#51, ), coalesce(status#52, ), 
coalesce(content_size#53, ), 200)
+- *Project [regexp_extract(val#13, ^([^\s]+\s), 1) AS hostname#49, 
regexp_extract(val#13, ^.*(\d\d/\w{3}/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} -\d{4}), 1) AS 
date#50, regexp_extract(val#13, ^.*"\w+\s+([^\s]+)\s*[(HTTP)]*.*", 1) AS 
path#51, regexp_extract(val#13, ^.*"\s+([^\s]+), 1) AS status#52, 
regexp_extract(val#13, ^.*\s+(\d+)$, 1) AS content_size#53]
              +- *Filter ((((regexp_extract(val#13, ^.*"\w+\s+([^\s]+)\s* 
[(HTTP)]*.*", 1) RLIKE .*(jpg|gif|png|xbm|jpeg|wav|mpg|pl)$ || 
(regexp_extract(val#13, ^([^\s]+\s), 1) = )) || (regexp_extract(val#13, 
^.*"\w+\s+([^\s]+)\s*[(HTTP)]*.*", 1) = )) || (regexp_extract(val#13, ^.* 
(\d\d/\w{3}/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} -\d{4}), 1) = )) || 
(regexp_extract(val#13, ^.*"\s+([^\s]+), 1) = ))
                 +- *FileScan csv [val#13] Batched: false, Format: CSV,
Location: 
InMemoryFileIndex[file:/C:/Users/M1047320/Desktop/access_log_Jul95], 
PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<val:string>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason showing split_df,bad_data_df takes significantly less time is because **Spark will only read and parse the needed lines for the show**. The data you read into Spark is broken into `Partitions`, which are fragments of data which will be divided between workers.

Once you call show on split_df,bad_data_df Spark will work only on small portion of the data (only 20 lines on split_df and only the first 20 bad lines on bad_data_df).

On the other hand, when calling show on good_data_df, Spark will have to process **all** the data (in the cost of both reading all the data, parsing it, and excluding the bad lines from the total).

If you have a simple way of defining bad lines, I would suggest adding another column with [UDF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction) - Boolean isBad, and filtering upon it. Simple passes over the data are much simpler than `except`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understood that spark transformations are lazy. My doubt is why fileScan is seen twice in physical plan even after caching

Answer (score 0):

Caching is not an action. So if you are doing split_df.cache() just before good_data_df.show(), the DAG will be created only for good_data_df.show and not split_df.cache. Caching for split_df will be performed as a stage but good_data_df will not be able to use that caching. To make good_data_df to use cached data just use split_df.take(1) after split_df.cache which will actually make split_df cached to be used by good_data_df.